# how to fade in a background image specified in CSS?

Tags: html, margin, fadein, css-animations

I've specified a background image using CSS.

I have tried using the keyframes and the webkit, moz, and o declarations within my selector to get it to **fade in** *on load*. So far this seems to work for me but it only works on the whole page and not just the ID singularly. It also causes margins around the whole page...

Does anyone have any advice or solutions?

```
#containerback {
    background-image: url(images/homebackground.png);
    background-attachment: inline;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 802px;
    width: 1440px;
    display: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; 
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}​
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident the only way you can do this is to fake it by making an element the same size and position behind the rest of the content and just fade that

Comment: On a side note you have some invalid property values with `display:fixed` and `background-attachment: inline`

Comment: Stupid question, but when you say "it only works on the whole page and not just the ID singularly." do you mean the page is larger than 1440 x 802?

Comment: thankyou @Zeaklous i have taken them out now.

Comment: the page isnt larger than 1440X802 @Mr Lister.

Comment: Then you should explain better. "It only works on the whole page" is not the way you want it, right? Then what do you want it to work on, and what should happen with the rest of the page?

Comment: I want my div #containerback to fade up so I've included the animation code inside #containerback. What's happening is my nav bar and header are also fading up.